# Issue declaring the Nexus3 repositories as remote repositories in Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, nexus

I am setting up Nexus3 repository as a remote repository in Artifactory.
But when I update the Nexus3 repo URL(https://domainname/repository/reponame/) & necessary credentials for authentication in the admin section, during testing i am getting,

> Connection failed: Error 404.

I have tried providing the rest URL(http://domainname/service/rest/repository/browse/reponame).
In this case, connection to the nexus server establishes successfully & able to see the directory structure for the remote repo in the Artifacts section , but could not find the artifacts inside & seeing below output/error,

> {   "errors" : [ {
>       "status" : 404,
>       "message" : "Couldn't find item: XXXX:XXXXXXX"   } ]

Comment: What type of repository is this (Maven, npm etc.)?

Comment: @DrorBereznitsky its Maven repository

Comment: also , I have tested the same with nexusV2, I was able to successfully authenticate to the nexusV2 server & able to pull artifacts from Artifactory, i have issue only when i test with NexusV3

Comment: Are you using a context path?  If you upgraded from NXRM2 to 3 and forgot to add the context path, that could be the difference.

Comment: Issue is  resolved, even though testing the settings gave 
"Connection failed: Error 404" .
I went ahead and saved the settings in Artifactory UI & ran a maven build using Artifactory URL, Artifactory was able to fetch artifacts from nexus remote repository

Comment: Are you able to browse the content on Artifactory? I have setup as well a remote repo and can use it with Gradle/Maven builds but pure content browsing on Artifactory does not work. It shows me only artifacts that got at least once downloaded by some build tools.

Answer (score 2):

You have to ignore the error while saving. This is because of a header mismatch.

Repo path should be like:

```
https://<host>:<port>/repository/reponame
```

Once you save the repository and try to download, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The test is failing when creating an Artifactory remote repository which point to a hosted Nexus repository, since Artifactory is using a HEAD request for checking the remote repository and for some reason Nexus will return a 404 (while returning a 200 when the same request is sent using the GET method). This behavior does not happen with Nexus group repositories.